# Parse bounced email

Tags: email

What is the best way to parse bounced (undeliverable) email?

When an email bounces back to my server, I would like to find why it bounced (soft/hard) and the undeliverable email address. Then I can deal with it appropriately in my database and/or flag the user to update their email when the log in next.

My goal is to protect my domain's mailing reputation. I only send transactional emails, but after time some of those in-boxes go stale and mail bounces back. I don't want to keep sending weekly emails to addresses that bounce.

I couldn't find many recent questions about this, and none had an actual solution:

1) [How to parse Delivery Status Notifications emails bounced from Mailer Deamons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172355/how-to-parse-delivery-status-notifications-emails-bounced-from-mailer-deamons)

2) [Automatically remove bounced email addresses from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035225/automatically-remove-bounced-email-addresses-from-database)

I expected there to be some kind of open source library to help parse undeliverable email, but can't seem to find anything like that. Surely people have been dealing with this issue for a long time...

I would like to deal with this on my server rather than going through services like sendgrid / mandrill / mailgun.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (I'm using Ubuntu and Postfix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**1) GREP**

It turns out that postfix keeps bounce information in it's log files. All permanent errors will have a dsn status beginning with 5. Using grep, you can get a list of emails with that status code:

```
grep " dsn=5." /var/log/mail.log | grep -o -P " to=<(.+?)>" | sort | uniq -c
```

The above gives all hard bounces. For soft bounces, use `" dsn=4."`.

The upside of this solution is that it is very easy to implement. The downside is we have to rely on postfix to correctly parse the message, and it may not work if you're sending to a mailing list, rather than to individual recipients.

**2) VERP**

Variable Envelope Return Path (VERP) uses a unique return path for every email recipient. (See [wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path))

Note that the 'return path' of an email is NOT the same as 'reply to'. The 'return path' is only used by mail servers to bounce emails back to the originating server when problems occur.

In short, let's say we're sending an email from *mymailinglist@mysite.com* to *richard@exapmle.com*. If you send it the normal way, you will get a bounce message and have to parse the message to figure out who it was sent to. But using verp, you set the return path to *bouncelist+richard+example.com@mysite.com*.

Now you can setup a mailbox specifically for bounced emails (bouncelist@mysite.com). By default postfix ignores anything after the "+" in the email address, so all bounced mail will go to the same place. But now the original email recipient (*richard@exapmle.com*) is contained in the return path and can be easily parsed out.

If you like, you can also send the mail directly to a script using a virtual mailbox. In /etc/postfix/virtual add the line

```
bouncelist: "| php mybounceparser.php"
```

This solution is certainly more complicated to implement, but may be the only option for large mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MailboxValidator free API to screen the email address prior to sending out any emails. It is after all better to avoid bounce if you can.

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/api-single-validation

That is if you are willing to write some codes.

Otherwise, your other option is to upload a CSV of your mailing list into the MailboxValidator bulk validation page and clean them. Once validation is done, you can download the results and import back into your database.